# ec2 run-instances and associate static IP address in one step?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-ip

Is it possible to launch an EC2 instance and associate an IP address in one step? Or does one need to manually do it after it's up?

Answer (score 1):

This must be done separately. (Padding)

Comment: What does "Padding" supposed to mean?

Comment: Padding out my short answer so that it's long enough to get through the SE minimum answer length requirement.

Comment: I'm generally not in favor of very short answers, but in cases like these, a short answer is all that is required.

Comment: Some reasoning behind it would make for a better answer.

Comment: How about "because the AWS API doesn't support it". :) If it did, the CLI tools would allow you to do this already.